# Apple Script - Create new Target and team selection

Tags: ios, xcode, applescript

[image]

As shown in the picture I have to pick team name from the following drop down but some how the team name doesn't gets picker using AppleScript. I am adding my AppleScript below :-

```
tell pop up button 1 of group "Signing" of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 2 of splitter group "MyApp.xcworkspace" of window "MyApp — MyApp.xcodeproj"
                click
                delay 1
                pick menu item "Team name to be picked" of menu 1
            end tell
```

Comment: Use **`click`** or **`select`** instead of **`pick`**.  It's also wise to replace the `delay` with code that performs a wait-and-check to ensure the `menu 1's menu item "..."` exists before trying to click something that might not be there.  All that being said, _XCode_ is scriptable, so are you sure you really have to go through the travesty of scripting its UI ?

Comment: Than you for the suggesstion.